# django - Records not saved in MySQL database but AutoIncrement gets increased

Tags: mysql, django, docker, mariadb, data-loss

I'm facing a weird one here.

I'm using `django` inside a `docker` container. When the system tries to save some records (mostly it works!) they don't end up in the database.

When I view the process in the debugger, the django objects gets saved, it gets an ID from the database and inside the django world everything seems fine.

But the record never shows up in the database! Even weirder: If I look at the table's meta options I see that per record which should have been created the `AutoIncrement` is increased. So it appears the database knows about the records but dedides not so save them...

I tried it on my Windows machine, the server runs UNIX, both have the same issue.

I'm using `django==2.0.9` and `mysqlclient==1.3.13` connecting to a `MariaDB`.

When I switch the table engine from `InnoDB` to `MyISAM` then it works.

Reproducibly it happens for the `django-axes` tables but I experienced the issue in other parts of the system as well. The calls come via the `django-restframework` to django.

Frankly I have no idea where to start looking for the issue.

1. On Windows and (server's) UNIX it occurs, on another's developers UNIX, it works
2. I downgraded latest `mysqlclient`, no effect
3. Google doesn't say anything or I'm not asking the right questions
4. MySQL error log keeps silent.
5. I also tried the latest `MariaDB` image `10.3`.

Comment: How are you looking at your database? Could there be some caching there that you're not aware of, so you actually don't see the live state of your db? If you open a Django shell, can you actually retrieve the objects, checking that they are saved using the django ORM? (I'm asking this because you said "inside the django world everything seems fine" but I don't understand what you mean by that)

Comment: The database is definetely empty. On the next time when axes tries to get or create, he always creates.

Comment: Still, what happens when you launch a shell, create the object there and save it?

Comment: via the shell it works... Resembles the fact that in most of the cases it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, without ever finding out what I can do about it, I switched the database engine for these explicit tables to `MyISAM`, now it works. Super weird.